# MySQL Query Slows Dramatically With Order BY included

Tags: mysql

I know this has been addressed, but the solutions have not helped me.

I have a table with 3 million records. The columns are indexed.

```
SELECT * FROM checklist_search WHERE player LIKE '%Mike%' AND player LIKE '%Trout%'
ORDER BY 0+year ASC, search_data ASC, 0+cardnumber ASC  
LIMIT 0, 50
```

Without the ORDER BY the query is fast - Query took 0.0156 sec
With the ORDER BY Query took 3.7068 sec

Based on other answers to this problem I tried

```
SELECT * FROM(SELECT * FROM checklist_search WHERE player LIKE '%Mike%' AND player LIKE '%Trout%'
  ) as myalias ORDER BY 0+year ASC, search_data ASC, 0+cardnumber ASC
LIMIT 0, 50
```

But the results are the same.

Here is the table and index structure

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `checklist_search` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `page_type` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `checklist_db` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `set_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `card_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `search_data` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `year` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `brand` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `issue` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `set_name` varchar(150) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `cardnumber` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `player` varchar(150) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `team` varchar(150) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `rc` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `sp` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `gu` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `auto` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `parallel` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `insert_card` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `card_count` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `image_count` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `print_run` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `display_image_front` varchar(120) NOT NULL,
  `display_image_back` varchar(120) NOT NULL,
  `seo_url` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `card_id` (`card_id`),
  KEY `checklist_db` (`checklist_db`),
  KEY `year` (`year`),
  KEY `player` (`player`),
  KEY `team` (`team`),
  KEY `print_run` (`print_run`),
  KEY `rc` (`rc`),
  KEY `set_id` (`set_id`),
  KEY `search_data` (`search_data`),
  KEY `cardnumber` (`cardnumber`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `player_2` (`player`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 PACK_KEYS=0 AUTO_INCREMENT=3203103 ;
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Mike

```
EDIT: Here is the result for 
EXPLAIN SELECT *
FROM checklist_search
WHERE player LIKE '%Mike%'
AND player LIKE '%Trout%'
ORDER BY year ASC , search_data ASC , cardnumber ASC
LIMIT 0 , 50

id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra   
1   SIMPLE  checklist_search    ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    2837591     Using where; Using filesort
```

Comment: The problem is that you compute the columns in the ORDER BY. So no index can be used. Just use `ORDER BY year ASC, search_data ASC, cardnumber ASC  `

Comment: I dropped the indexes on year, search_data, and cardnumber and the results were the same.

Comment: Don't drop the indexes! Use the columns in the ORDER BY without computing them like adding `0`. That prevents the use of indexes because now you don't just use the column by itself. The DB engine now has to convert and caclulate the column for every record and can't use the predefined index. Add the indexes again and use the ORDER BY from my comment above

Comment: To make what juergen is saying crystal clear, MySQL does not use indexes on calculated fields; which is what you are doing when ordering by anything other than simple field references. My guess is you are doing `+0` because you want numeric ordering, `CAST()` would be more self-documenting, but still not use indices. Your only real option in that case is changing your table so that those fields are of appropriate types.

Comment: thanks for clarifying. It was the same either way. I put the 0+ in to make it sort numerically. I took the 0+ out and the results are the same. I put the indexes back :-)

Comment: Then run `explain select ...` and add the output to your question. There you can see which indexes are used and which not

Comment: @Uueerdo the two columns where I had 0+ where both primarily number data but sometimes not. Putting the 0+ in gave me a sort I was happy with. But either way it seems the indexes are not being used when sorting as the time for the query was the same with or without the 0+

I also tried removing some of the sorts, and the results did not vary

Comment: @juergend I have added the EXPLAIN result.

Comment: try adding `(year, search_data, cardnumber)` as a single index

Comment: @Fabricator thank you. I did that just now. The results were the same as far as time, but EXPLAIN said it was using the index I created

Comment: that's strange. does running explain without `order by` show using a different index?

Comment: @Fabricator Without Order BY EXPLAIN shows the some thing as WITH Order By, except using filesort is not there